# How to Run script when unity load just once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here, I am looking for a piece of code in the Unity editor that will execute the initial panel of the created package only once when Unity is opened, but this code is executed in the initial frame every time I play Unity and then stop it, and it continuously shows the panel. Gives. I want it to be seen only once when the project is opened.

```cs
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class Autorun
{
    static Autorun()
    {
        EditorApplication.update += RunOnce;
    }

    static void RunOnce()
    {
        Debug.Log("Once"); // but it will repeat every time I Clicking on play then stop it.
        
        Panel.Init();
        
        EditorApplication.update -= RunOnce;
    }
}
```

Above is the code suggested by the user in [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/45186/can-i-auto-run-a-script-when-editor-launches-or-a.html), which was chosen as the best answer, but in fact, as I pointed out, it had a problem.

Comment: Did you try the next answer which points out this exact situation?

Comment: @hijinxbassist Thank you for your response, luckily a few moments after I wrote this question I tried the solution you mentioned and it worked.

Comment: Good deal, I will have to remember that one for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Although it was mentioned in the comment that the second answer in Unity answers solves the problem, after a while I noticed that the panel opens again when saving the code and I could not find a way to block it through another condition in `EditorApplication`. The solution below is the final method of solving the problem that uses `EditorPrefs` and I feel it necessary to share this method with you.

```cs
internal const string FIRST_TIME = "FIRST_TIME"; // the key

static Autorun()
{
    EditorApplication.update += RunOnce;
    EditorApplication.quitting += Quit;
}

private static void Quit() => EditorPrefs.DeleteKey(FIRST_TIME);
private static void RunOnce()
{
    var firstTime = EditorPrefs.GetBool(FIRST_TIME, true);
    
    Debug.Log(firstTime);
    
    if (firstTime)
    {
        EditorPrefs.SetBool(FIRST_TIME, false);

        if (EditorPrefs.GetBool(Panel.ShowOnStart, true)) Panel.Init();
    }
    EditorApplication.update -= RunOnce;
}
}
```